# Bug navigating question/answer list in profile returns to page 1

Tags: bug, profile-page, question-lists, internet-explorer

When viewing the list of questions (or answers) in my profile, I click a question (or answer) to read. When I want to go back to the list, I navigate "back". This returns me to the first page of the list, regardless of which page I was on. However, the URL indicates that I am on the correct page, and I am unable to click that link to that page to return until I load another page ("next" works, though, so a 2-pager wouldn't be impossible).

This makes it pretty annoying to try to read posts in any logical order (votes, activity or newest).

[image]

I've reproduced this reliably in IE8 on SO and MSO sorting questions and answers, and EL&U with answers.

Comment: Uhoh, IE8; this works just fine in FF14, in case you wanted to know that..

Comment: I can hardly contain my surprise

Comment: Note that for this to work properly in browsers, you need to use the history API, which IE8 (nor IE9) support. See http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Comment: Dude, you are using IE and complaining about bugs? Seriously? You are lucky enough that you are not paying taxes on SE like you would do on some other sites (http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/microsoft/9331808/Australian-retailer-Kogan-hits-Internet-Explorer-7-users-with-extra-tax.html). Try using a real web browser. You will see the world wide web from a different angle. Personally, the only scenario when IE is useful to me and when I actually use it is when I reinstall Windows, I use it to download a web browser for my OS.

Comment: Whoa, deep breath, @DarinDimitrov. Some people work on super-locked-down corporate machines.